# Is there a way to control position of UIPopoverController when using Storyboards and Segues?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

The title should say it all. I have built a small app for iPad with Storyboards. I have an `embeddedTableView` container with some 4 buttons that point to `UIPopoverControllers`. I put `ViewControllers` for each of the `PopOvers`. I don't know, maybe this wasn't needed. But some of the Popovers open in a funny position. I would like to be able to control where they open.

Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by a "funny position".  Can you post some images otherwise I'm not sure that anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You have full control of where they open from.  If your buttons are UIBarButtonItems then you can use presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:.  If they are UIButtons then you can use presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated: , giving it the CGRect of the button.